# Why does Forth use IF statement THEN ... instead of ENDIF?

Tags: history, language-design, forth

Why does Forth use IF statement THEN ... instead of ENDIF?

I'm implementing a (non-conforming) Forth compiler thing. Basically, Forth's syntax appears very counter-intuitive to me regarding IF statements.

```
IF ."Statement is true"
ELSE ."Statement is not true"
THEN ."Printed no matter what;
```

Why is the ending statement a `THEN`? This makes the language read extremely weird to me. For my compiler, I'm considering changing it to something like `ENDIF` which reads more natural. But, what was the rationale behind having backwards IF-THEN statements in the first place?

Comment: Does anyone think this would be better suited for programmers.se?

Comment: You'll have to ask Chuck Moore. Nobody else will know the answer. [Here he states when he introduced "The sometime-criticised postfix conditional"](http://www.colorforth.com/HOPL.html).

Comment: If I am not much mistaken, there are (or, perhaps, were) implementations (can't quite remember which at the moment, sorry) where ENDIF was defined as a kind of synonym of THEN, which means you aren't first to find the sequence of `IF-ELSE-THEN` a bit too unusual. Me, I've never had a problem with it, though. (I think I saw an explanation for it in some book long ago, and it was along the lines of @AshleyF has said in his answer.)

Comment: @AndriyM: Win32Forth is one of those implementations.

Comment: @RaymondChen That link is now broken, here's the archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20160313034132/http://www.colorforth.com/HOPL.html

Comment: You're associating the keyword with what comes after it; in Forth, you should instead associate it with what comes before, just as you do with postfix arithmetic. Forth takes the sequence`IF condition THEN action` and turns it into into `condition IF action THEN`, which seems eminently reasonable in postfix-land.

Answer (score 13):

Just think of it as, "`IF` that's the case, do this, `ELSE` do that ... and `THEN` continue with ..."

Or better yet, use quotations (as in [Factor](http://factorcode.org/), [RetroForth](http://retroforth.org/), ...) in which case it's completely postfix without special compile-time words; just regular words taking addresses from the stack: `[ do this ] [ do that ] if` or `[ do this ] when` or `[ do that ] unless`. I personally much prefer this.

*Aside RE: quotations*

Here is [how quotations are compiled in RetroForth](http://rx-core.org/dev/corpse/article/188). In my own Forth (which compiles to my own VM), I simply added a `QUOTE` instruction that pushes the next address to the stack and jumps over n-bytes. The n-bytes are expected to be terminated by a `RETURN` instruction and the `if`, `when`, `unless` words consume a predicate along with the address(es) left by preceding quotations; calling as appropriate. Very simple indeed, and quotations generally open the door for [all kinds of beautiful abstractions away from thinking about the stack](http://elasticdog.com/2008/12/beginning-factor-shufflers-and-combinators/).

Comment: I've never heard of quotations! That looks like an excellent abstraction mechanism though. When I first set out on this project I was wondering if it was even possible to have anonymous functions in Forth

Comment: This may or may not apply to this situation, but part 1 of "The Joy of Concatenative Languages" ([Part 1](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/cat/the-joy-of-concatenative-languages-part-1), [Part 2](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/cat/the-joy-of-concatenative-languages-part-2), [Part 3](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/cat/the-joy-of-concatenative-languages-part-3)) states: "Conditionals also look quite weird at first glance, but under the surface they are profoundly elegant ..."

Comment: I've got one problem with it after thinking it through a bit more. How would you implement something like `1 [ 10 ] [ 20 ] if .` The expected output should be `10`.. But, it gets the stack out of line and when the quotation "returns", it returns to either `10` or `20` which isn't right. Or should this just be implemented with an secondary "hidden" call stack for such internal returns?

Comment: I don't know the particulars of your Forth but, in mine for example, `true [ 10 ] [ 20 ] if` compiles to bytecode `LIT -1 QUOTE 3 LIT 10 RETURN QUOTE 3 LIT 20 RETURN IF`. The `LIT` instruction pushes its operand as a literal. `QUOTE` pushes the address following its operand and jumps over n-bytes (3 in this case). So, when `IF` is reached, there is a `-1` and two addresses on the stack. `if` consumes all three of these values and calls one or the other address depending on the boolean (BTW, I use `-1` for `true` so that there's no difference between logical and bitwise `and`, `or`, `not`...)

Comment: Oh, and `IF` pushes the immediately following address to the return stack before calling into one or the other quotation (just a normal call) so that, upon `RETURN`, execution resumes after the `IF`.

Comment: A link that readers may find relevant: the GForth documentation specifically addresses the uses of 'then' in English, and how Forth uses a meaning that's less commonly seen in programming languages. https://gforth.org/manual/Selection.html